# If i am setting up metamask for a local ganache server only, do i need infura at all?

Tags: metamask, infura

I will build my own metamask from the open source code, becuase I want to have my password stored so that i can run tests without having to click on metamask and confirm my password.

While setting up this local dev metamask, i can see it wants me to setup an infura account - but is this only if i want this metamask to talk to the ethereum network (or any other non-local network)? Or do i need infura for talking to a local ganache?

Answer (score 0):

- Can you interact with local ganache server without Infura ?
- Yes
  So, You don't need any Nodes provider like Infura, Alchemy if you work locally.

Comment: have you built a local metamask? just wondering bc  it's taking... forever.

Comment: because honestly i think i *need* an infra id just to get this thing to compile. i get that it doesn't need it...

Comment: You have to change the inside code which is planted for seeking infura Id. Edit that code and you are good to go